# Word for going through the motions / doing something because you are supposed to

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, adverbs

I use **perfunctorily** a lot.

Then I learned I use it wrong.

I thought it meant to do something *dispassionately* or *because you have to* or to *go through the motions*. But actually it means

> carried out with a minimum of effort or reflection. (NOAD)

Now, this isn't too different from the meaning I thought, because if you are doing something dispassionately or by obligation or are just going through the motions then you will carry it out with minimum effort or reflection, but the definition does not capture all that I thought it did.

**What is the word that I want?**

I fear I am not being clear. I fear that my desired definition and the real definition are too similar.

My desired definition *includes* "carried out with a minimum of effort or reflection" but it also includes a *sense of obligation*. You can do something with minimal effort because you want to do it but are just low in energy or because you are distracted or because you are hurried. The word I seek would make clear that the minimal effort is due to a lack of care—perhaps even more than a lack of care: maybe even disdain for the task.

**This word would probably perfectly describe how most of us would perform tasks at a minimum wage job we have held too long.** We would do it, maybe even well, but without any real care for it.

**Another example.** I ask this question now because I was going to write that people often pray "perfunctorily"—it is not heartfelt; it is done because people think that prayer is supposed good and important, but don't actually feel that it is.

**I tried to find the word I want.**

- *Cursorily, briefly, hastily* include an aspect of speed. The word I seek doesn't need to mean the action happened quickly; indeed the lack of desire might even mean it happens slowly.
- *Dispassionately* does not incorporate the sense of obligation.
- *Obligatorily* does not incorporate the lack of thoughtfulness. You can do something obligatorily and meticulously.
- *Going through the motions* is probably closest but, being a phrase, is difficult to turn into an adverb or even adjective. (Alternate, lesser answer would give me *going through the motions* in adverb form.)

Comment: I think *obligatorily* connotes a certain lack of passion...

Comment: By the way M-W gives a definition of *perfunctory* that fits your bill: "used to describe something that is done without energy or enthusiasm because of habit or because it is expected."

Comment: I was being too cutesy and mirroring the reason against dispassionately. I will fix. More meant that you can do something obligatorily and thoughtfully

Comment: Do you really want me to [*phone in*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=phone%20it%20in) another answer?

Comment: It makes sense to check in more than a single dictionary, especially when the sense you have been comfortable using isn't given by one. And [NOAD](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143629/is-there-an-english-equivalent-of-this-common-maldivian-proverb-meaning-to-do-s) does give: go through the motions
...

 do something perfunctorily, without any enthusiasm or commitment; simulate an action: a child goes through the motions of washing up.

Comment: **half-assed** comes to mind.

Comment: I’m a little confused; ISTM that *going through the motions* implies a level of inattentiveness that you seem not to want.  That said, *insincerely* may be part of (or related to) the answer you seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From M-W:

> [*perfunctory*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfunctory): used to describe something that is done without
>   energy or enthusiasm because of habit or **because it is expected** [emphasis added]

From Dictionary.com:

> [*perfunctory*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/perfunctory?s=t):
>   performed merely as **a routine duty**; hasty and superficial [emphasis added]

These definitions of *perfunctory* fit your original sense well. You weren't using *perfunctorily* incorrectly.

Comment: This is general reference. Almost any other dictionary shows clearly that the word OP suggests has the meaning he requires.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not so, the definitions in some dictionaries (e.g., Oxford Dictionaries, Macmillan) don't include the sense of obligation the OP is seeking. Some do, some don't. I tried to direct my answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Yet if OP had googled 'perfunctory meaning', they would (assuming they see what I do) have seen as the third hit: 'Perfunctory | Definition of Perfunctory by Merriam-Webster
www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfunctory
—used to describe something that is done without energy or enthusiasm because of habit or because it is expected.' I'd say that's general reference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agree. That's precisely what I did and what I referenced. Thanks.

Comment: Silenus probably did exactly the same. And, as OP should have done this, added a 'comment' rather than an 'answer'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth With regard to "OP should have done this": Is it written somewhere that under those circumstances (if and when one can determine "what the OP should have done"), users should comment on rather than answer questions? In my limited time on ELU, I see little consistency on this issue. I also see many users commenting on rather than answering well-framed questions, and doing so without providing supporting references. Is this what we want? BTW, Silenus's second comment wasn't there when I started typing my answer.

Comment: OALD: 'done as **a duty** or habit, without real interest, attention or feeling': _
a perfunctory nod/smile_ (bolding mine ). Macmillan is now closed.

Answer (score 3):

*Doing one's duty*

She went to church *dutifully* to please her mother.

I did my *duty*.

It was a *dutiful* prayer, but not a heartfelt one.

Answer (score 2):

He prayed in a **robotic** act/expression of piety. (I am using the adjective of the noun robot).

**Robot:**

1). A machine that...does mechanical, routine tasks on command; [and]

2). **A person who acts and responds in a mechanical , routine manner...** [as in an act/expression of piety].

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 2):

Your use of **perfunctorily** is fine, but as an alternative you can use **rote** to convey the meaning you were intending:

**[Rote](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rote)**

> **noun**
>
> 1. routine; a fixed, habitual, or mechanical course of procedure:
>
> *the rote of daily living.*
>
> **adjective**
>
> 2. proceeding mechanically and repetitiously; being mechanical and repetitious in nature; routine; habitual: rote performance; rote
>    implementation;
>
> *His behavior became more rote with every passing year.*