# What is a word meaning something you do only as a required action to meet a formal requirement?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is a word meaning something you do with a minimal effort and with no other intention than to satisfy a formal requirement?

For example, if someone named Jurgen had to buy property in Bulgaria in order to meet some kind of business requirement to operate there, but he wanted to operate his business in a rental property, so he bought an unreachable 1000-square-meter parcel of land in the middle of nowhere:

> Jurgen's ___ purchase of land was just a way to thumb his nose at the Bulgarian bureaucracy, while still allowing him to open the sporting goods store on schedule.

(Not my real example, but this is the same intent.)

**Perfunctory** is really really close, but not quite, and it sounds a little pretentious... Somehow the word "token" in its derogatory sense is close, but not quite. The words "spurious" and "fabricated" and "pretense" and "fraudulent" imply illegality, but the example is not illegal, just something to comply with the letter of the law.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: It’s not single word, and it doesn't fit in the adjective slot, but the idiom *going through the motions* might work.

Comment: Idiom:  *letter of the law*.  Or, *loophole*?

Comment: Token would fit there, or similar words like minimal, nominal, but none has the full meaning you want. You might have to combine them with contemptuous, contumacious, derisory, and use 2 adjectives.

Comment: You don't seem to understand how it works. The 1000 sqm parcel is owned by the brother of the guy issuing the license, and you paid a premium for it. There are plenty of words for that - graft, baksheesh, etc.

Comment: Duplicate of [word for _going through the motions_ – _doing something because you are supposed to_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356166/word-for-going-through-the-motions-doing-something-because-you-are-supposed-to/356167#356167).

Comment: Not a dupe, because I explicitly **do not want** "perfunctory".

Comment: **If he bought the land, it would not be a "rental property"**. However, a required action in a bureacratic context, is **compliance** and **compliant**.

Comment: Sounds like the action is **pro forma** to me.

Comment: @Lambie He bought land to fulfill a requirement, so he could do rentals elsewhere.

Comment: @YosefBaskin OK. So his purchase is compliant with Bulgarian law.

Comment: Duplicate of 'word for going through the motions – doing something because you are supposed to'.  Ignore the answer 'perfunctory' and look at other answers (if any). If none meet your requirements, the correct procedure is to offer a 'bounty'. The _question_ there covers this.

Comment: The example is rather confusing: there seem to be three items in it ((1) the land in the middle of nowhere, (2) some business in a rental property, (3) a sporting goods store), and it is not at all clear what the relationships among them are. I take it that what is at the core of the example is that what motivated him to purchase the land is not what usually motivates people to purchase land, nor what the government had in mind when it enacted the law.

Comment: Lessee - What was that word Maynard used??

Comment: Without the OP coming back to clarify the example, it is difficult to be sure, but this might be a duplicate of [Emphasizing or observing the letter but not the spirit of the law](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362218). The answer ***gaming the system*** given there seems particularly relevant here, although it may not fit the OP's purposes because it is not a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yosef Baskin gave you a great answer, albeit in a comment. From Merriam-Webster:

**pro forma** (adj., sense 1): made or carried out in a perfunctory manner or as a formality.

Although the definition includes the word "perfunctory," pro forma has different connotations. It does not necessarily imply boredom, halfheartedness, or lack of thoroughness. It simply suggests that the action was done primarily or solely for the sake of following the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Something you do only as a required action to meet a formal requirement is a...

> **formality**   (noun - OED definition 8)
> *A ceremony; a formal act or observance; a legal, authorized, or customary procedure.*

It's often used in the plural...

> [*Let's dispense with **the formalities***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dispense%20with%20the%20formalities%22)

Comment: A formality is normally something that is purely a matter of form. For example, some of the formalities that the purchaser needs to satisfy may be that the documents about his purchase of the land be printed on a certain kind of paper, or that they be stamped in some municipal office. Here there is, however, an actual parcel of land that he will end up owning 'for real', and that seems to go beyond pure form.

Comment: But "a formal act or observance ... or customary procedure" ***is*** "a matter of form"! The fact that some "mere formalities" occur *within the context of significant acts* doesn't make any difference. Such formalities could in fact be dispensed with in any given legal procedure, for example, and the legal position would be unaffected. That's why they ***are*** "mere formalities"!